# Configuring Postsharp logging toolkit

Tags: c#, aop, postsharp

Using the free version of Postsharp, I added a logging aspect (using the toolkit, didn't code it myself). Later I changed my mind and wanted to log only upon entering a function, and not on leaving.

Where can this be configured? Couldn't find it anywhere.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Diagnostics configuration is stored in solution (*.pssln) or project level configuration file (*.psproj). These files may not contain required configuration tags or even they may be missing by default.

You can open the configuration wizard from smart tag over any method without [Log] attribute. The configuration you are interested in is on the first page (Logging Level). Note that there is *"New logging profile..."* at the bottom of this page - you can have multiple configurations within one application.

If you change diagnostics configuration then pssln file is created after completing the wizard and it should contain something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project xmlns="http://schemas.postsharp.org/1.0/configuration" xmlns:d="clr-namespace:PostSharp.Patterns.Diagnostics;assembly:PostSharp.Patterns.Diagnostics" xmlns:p="http://schemas.postsharp.org/1.0/configuration" xmlns:p1="http://schemas.postsharp.org/1.0/configuration">
  <Property Name="LoggingEnabled" Value="{has-plugin('PostSharp.Patterns.Diagnostics')}" Deferred="true" />
  <d:LoggingProfiles p:Condition="{$LoggingEnabled}">
    <d:LoggingProfile Name="Default" OnExceptionLevel="None" OnSuccessLevel="None" />
  </d:LoggingProfiles>
</Project>
```

The interesting tag is d:LoggingProfile with it's attributes OnExceptionLevel and OnSuccessLevel. You can add this configuration file manually as well.

Comment: Thanks. This file was created in the solution level after right clicking the solution and choosing "Add new postsharp policy". Your comment did the trick.